# Data Binding in Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, builder

I have an application that has 2 objects in it: A `List` and a `ComboBox`. In the `List` I have a set of items. When one of the items is clicked on, I want the `ComboBox's` items to change. I have this code so far but I can't figure out where to go from here.

```
protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            if(list.selectedItem.stores == "Dodge")
            {

                //comboBox.?????
            }
        }
```

I have Data Services by Cold Fusion that are set in the project as well. I have a list of stores, `Dodge Toyota Hyundai Mazda Nissan Jacksonville` that populate the `List`. There are several hundred `Names` in the `ComboBox` data that need to be filtered when a user chooses a store. For example, If I choose the `Dodge` store, I want the combo box to be populated with only the users who's store property is `Dodge`. How do I do that? I hope this all makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the data provider for combobox like

```
protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
    {
        if(list.selectedItem.stores == "Dodge")
        {
            comboBox.dataProvider=array; 
            //or
            comboBox.dataProvider=xmlList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to approach this situation. Which direction you take, depends on your use case (of which I know too little).

## Load'm all and filter'm

You make one big list of all possible items that could appear in the ComboBox. You make sure that these items have a `parentId` property. You can then use this property to filter items when the user selects an item from the List.

```
private var comboboxItems:ArrayCollection;

override public function initialize():void {
    super.initialize();
    
    myService.getAllComboboxItems(setComboboxItems);
}

private function setComboboxItems(event:ResultEvent):void {
    combobox.dataprovider = comboboxItems = event.result as ArrayCollection;
    comboboxItems.filterFunction = isParentSelected;
}

private function isParentSelected(item:ComboboxItem):Boolean {
    return item.parentId = list.selectedItem.id;
}

protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
    if (list.selectedItem.stores == "Dodge") {
        comboboxItems.refresh(); 
    }
}
```

Note: this is just code I'm writing of the top of my head, so it probably won't work out of the box, but it conveys the idea.

## Load'm when you need'm

Each time an item is selected in the List, make a service call to get the corresponding ComboBox items and set the dataProvider with the incoming result.

```
protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
    if (list.selectedItem.stores == "Dodge") {
        service.getComboBoxItemsByParentId(list.selectedItem.id, setComboboxItems); 
    }
}

private function setComboboxItems(event:ResultEvent):void {
    combobox.dataprovider = event.result as ArrayCollection;
}
```